# Why does my validation form gives true after first if statement while it should give an false

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

My validation form works properly at the first if statement and also at the next if statements as long as I keep out the innerHTML error message statement. When I add the innerHTML to the next if statement the function gives true while it should give false. But I need to display the error message after every if statement and not turn true while it should be false.

```
function checkforblank() {

    var errormessage = "";

    if(document.getElementById("validationCustom01").value == "") {
        errormessage += "Voer a.u.b. uw voornaam in.";
        document.getElementById("invalid-feedback1").innerHTML=errormessage;
        document.getElementById("validationCustom01").style.borderColor = "red";
    }

    if(document.getElementById("validationCustom02").value == "") {
        errormessage += "Voer a.u.b. uw achternaam in.";
        document.getElementById("invalid-feedback2").innerHTML=errormessage;
        document.getElementById("validationCustom02").style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    var email = document.getElementById("validationCustom03").value;
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if(!email.match(mailformat) || email == "") {
        errormessage += "Voer a.u.b. een geldig email adres in. \n";
        document.getElementById("validationCustom03").style.borderColor = "red";
    }            
    var zipcode = document.getElementById("validationCustom05").value;
    var zipcodeformat = /^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{2}$/i;
    if(!zipcode.match(zipcodeformat) || zipcode == "") {
        errormessage += "Voer a.u.b. een geldige postcode in.";
        document.getElementById("validationCustom05").style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("validationCustom06").value == "") {
        errormessage += "Voer a.u.b. uw huisnummer in. \n";
        document.getElementById("validationCustom06").style.borderColor = "red";
    }

    if(errormessage != "") {
        alert("Controleer de velden");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Every field should show a message when the user input is not according the requirements. Now it only shows one message.

```
<form class="formIncentro" method="post" action=[next page]"welkom.html" onsubmit="return checkforblank()">
    <div class="form-row" style="max-width: 60rem;">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom01">Voornaam</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" name="voornaam" placeholder="Voornaam">
            <div id="invalid-feedback1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom011">Tussenvoegsel</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom011">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom02">Achternaam</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Achternaam">
            <div class="invalid-feedback2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-3" style="max-width: 90rem;">
            <label for="validationCustom03">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03" placeholder="Email">
            <div class="invalid-feedback3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mb-3" style="max-width: 60rem;">
            <label for="validationCustom05">Postcode</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom05" placeholder="Postcode">
            <div class="invalid-feedback5"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom06">Huisnummer</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom06" placeholder="Huisnummer">
            <div class="invalid-feedback6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row" style="max-width: 60rem;">
        <div class="col-md-7 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom07">Straatnaam</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom07" placeholder="Straatnaam">
            <div class="invalid-feedback7"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
            <label for="validationCustom08">Plaatsnaam</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom08" placeholder="Plaatsnaam">
            <div class="invalid-feedback8"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: so you are concatenating to a string and outputting that same string to multiple elements on the page. `errormessage += "Voer a.u.b. uw voornaam in.";` and `errormessage += "Voer a.u.b. uw achternaam in.";` so when you out the error message to `...."invalid-feedback2").innerHTML=errormessage` it will have error 1 and error 2.

Comment: Please add your html structure to help us diagnose what is occurring.

Comment: @epascarello. What do you mean by then it will have error 1 and error 2?

Comment: @klabranche , I have added my html.

Comment: basically `var error = ""; error += "one"; console.log(error); error += "two"; console.log(error);`

Comment: Do not do concatenation, just output that error message in that spot.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks I solved that one by taking out the +.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your invalid-feedback divs 2-8 are not id'd.  You have set their `class` to your id.

```
<div class="invalid-feedback3"></div>
```

should be:

```
<div id="invalid-feedback3"></div>
```

The `getElementById` line is likely causing an error and the function call is stopped

```
document.getElementById("invalid-feedback2").innerHTML=errormessage;
```

before you ever get to your check to return false.

```
if(errormessage != "") {
    alert("Controleer de velden");
    return false;
}
```

This will  show the first error as that code is correct but will never show the rest as they are all incorrectly not getting the feedback divs.